# How to implement custom middleware in Nextjs 13 App Router for API

Tags: node.js, express, rest, next.js13, zod

How to implement this express validation approach in nextJs 13/14 App router?

In express I'm doing this to avoid repeating yourself in doing validation by having a validateRequest middleware which we can provide a validator schemas for body, params, etc...

**auth-route.ts**

```
import { Router, Request, Response } from "express"
import { validateRequest } from "validate-request";

const authRouter = Router();

authRouter.get("/", (req : Request, res : Response) => {
    res.status(200).send("Nothing here")
})

authRouter.post("/login", validateRequest({body : UserLoginValidation}), loginUser)

authRouter.post("/register", validateRequest({ body : UserRegisterValidation }), registerUser)

export default authRouter
```

**validate-request.ts**

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express"
import z, { AnyZodObject, ZodError} from "zod"

export default interface validators {
  params?: AnyZodObject,
  body?: AnyZodObject,
  query?: AnyZodObject,
}

export const validateRequest = ( validators : validators ) => {
    return async (req : Request, res : Response, next : NextFunction) => {
        try{
            if(validators.body){
                req.body = await validators.body?.parseAsync(req.body);
            }
            // if(validators.params){
            //
            // }
            // ... other validators
            next();
        }catch(e){
            if(e instanceof ZodError){
                console.log(e)
                next(new Error(e.issues[0].message))
                res.status(400)
            }
            next(e)
        }
    }
}
```

**auth-validator.ts**

```
import z from "zod";

export const UserRegisterValidation = z.object({
    name: z.string({ required_error : "name is required"}).min(1, "name is required"),
    email: z.string({ required_error : "email is required"}).email("email must be valid"),
    password: z
        .string({ required_error : "password is required"})
        .min(8, "Password must be minimum of 8 characters")
        .refine(
            (value) =>
                /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@#^&])/.test(value),
            "Password must include uppercase, lowercase, digit, and special character."
        ),
});

export const UserLoginValidation = z.object({
    email: z.string({ required_error : "email is required"}).email("invalid email"),
    password: z.string({ required_error : "password is required"}).min(1, "password is required"),
});
```

How can I implement this on Nextjs 13/14 App router?

this is my **auth/route.ts**

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

import { userLoginSchema } from "@/validation/schemas/auth-schema";

export const PATCH = async (req: NextRequest) => {
    try {
        const { user } = await req.json();
        const validated = userLoginSchema.safeParse(user);

        if (!validated.success) return NextResponse.json({ message: validated.error.issues[0].message },{ status: 400 });

        //......

        return NextResponse.json("ok");
    } catch (e) {
        return NextResponse.json(
            { message: `INTERNAL SERVER: ${e}` },
            { status: 500 }
        );
    }
};
```

So I can get rid of these validation code on each GET, POST, PUT, DELETE ...etc.

```
        const validated = userLoginSchema.safeParse(user);

        if (!validated.success) return NextResponse.json({ message: validated.error.issues[0].message },{ status: 400 });
```

Thank you for helping